# Access files from Linux installation in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot, file-transfer

I'm using Windows and Linux on a laptop. I want to access the Linux files from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how your window/linux is set up on your laptop. Are you using virtual machine or is configured as dual boot. If the latter, you can use tools like [explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) to drag drop files when your windows is booted. Otherwise, if linux is booted, you can mount your windows partition using [ntfs-3g](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) and copy files to windows. If you are on Virtual machine like Virtualbox or vmware, then consult your manuals to see how its down

Answer (score 0):

Setup a [Samba](http://samba.org/) server on the Linux machine.

There's also [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), which includes pscp which will transfer stuff through the SSH server.

Edit (upon re-reading the question): You can mount the NTFS drive in Linux using the [ntfs-3g](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) file system driver.

Comment: "in a single laptop"

Answer (score 0):

Try [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs)

> [image]
>
> Explore2fs is a GUI explorer tool for accessing ext2 and ext3 filesystems. It runs under all versions of Windows and can read almost any ext2 and ext3 filesystem.
>
> A beta version of Virtual Volumes is now available. This is a technology preview for Explore2fs 2. Virtual Volumes also has the ability to read ReiserFS and many other filesyste

Answer (score 0):

In a VMware machine, is just a matter of having installed the VMware tools, then it's drag and drop.

It does not sound you're having that, but 2 native OSes. I'd do it in this way:

- You will need to know in which partition is your Windows, in your disk. You'll have seen it while partitioning at install (there are other ways to check which it is, later on). Let's suppose it's hda1 (but you need to be sure).
- Open a console window.
- Create a directory in which the windows partition will be "mounted" (don't worry, you are not changing your windows partition). To do so, just type in the console:

  ```
  mkdir /mnt/windows
  ```

  now you need to actually mount it:

  ```
  mount -t vfat /dev/hda1 /mnt/windows
  ```
- Then, to access it, you just type:

  ```
  cd /mnt/windows
  ```
- Or browse by your Gnome, KDE, or whichever desktop, to that location.

Other way is to just use a USB stick.

Comment: If the Windows uses NTFS, then it should be "mount -t ntfs /dev/hda1 /mnt/windows" instead of "mount -t vfat /dev/hda1 /mnt/windows".

Comment: yep, actually, I should have used ntfs for the explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your linux partitions are ext2/3 - use explore2fs (links to it are in other posts). If you are running ReiserFS, try http://yareg.akucom.de/. If you are on another filesystem you should google for it.